# Watering Schedule: Large Jade Crosby

Tags: watering, jade

I have a large jade crosby plant. The plant is 2'4" tall, with a 7" trunk circumference at the base. It sits at a south facing window in my apartment.

I was wondering about watering schedule. I read online that during winter I should water about once a month. However, I haven’t been able to find how much water I should be giving it, since it is a larger plant. Right now I have been giving it 16oz of water every month.

The plant has been dropping leaves and branches consistently for the past 2 months. However, it also has some new growth. I am not sure whether this has been an over or under watering issue. There is not any other visible disease or pests on the plant.

How often should I water, and when I do how much water should I be giving it?

## [imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb5IX.jpg)

[image: jade crosby]
[image: jade closup]

Comment: Make sure that if it drops more leaves, you save them and put them lying down on the soil. New baby plants will propagate!

Answer (score 4):

That's a sure sign of stress.Don’t water your jade plant on a schedule. Rather, water your jade plant when the top of soil is just dry to the touch. Also see the soil at the base of the plant, if it's dry water it.The most important factors to consider when growing jade houseplants is water, light, temperature, and fertilizer.Every plant needs some type of light. Also the room may be too warm for the plant and that may be drying it out.We used to grow them. They are somewhat temperamental.

Answer (score 3):

That is a very nice Jade plant.  The leaves look plump which means they have enough water.  How much you should water depends on the light levels, soil type and the pot arrangements.

- in winter months reduce water quantity so the leaves are still plump to the touch.
- optimum soil type is sharp sand (builder's sand) with a little organic matter like peat moss or fine compost
- it looks like the inner pot is surrounded by white Styrofoam peanuts.  Is it possible that the plant is sitting in water?

Although a bit messy I recommend removing the plant and inner pot to have a look at what is happening inside the outer pot. Jades tend to have a dense but fine root system.  They will not do well if they are sitting in water.

For the quantity of water I recommend cutting the amount by half for the next few months and then slowly increasing as spring arrives.

Comment: Underwatering or not watering at all doesn't seem to cause any problems. A neighbor of mine has a couple of huge indoor jades that she has on many occasions let go bone-dry for weeks if not months. They bounce right back as soon as she resumes watering. She has had both of them for more than a decade.